# How to click on the second element in capybara with css

Tags: rspec, capybara

I have a set of following code inside table:

```
<i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
```

I am using capybara and I want to click on the second element.
I tried using:

```
page.all(:xpath, "//i[@class='fa fa-pen']")[1].trigger('click') -->resulted in clicking all elements
```

and

```
page.all(:xpath, "//i[@class='fa fa-pen']")[1].click -->resulted in ClickFailed error.
```

I would like to know if there is anyway I can click the second element without using 'within'.

Following is the HTML

```
<div>
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a>
                        <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <a>
                        <i class="fa fa-pen"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<table>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually HTML page is lot bigger. Thought of sharing only relevant parts.

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `find(:xpath, ”//i[@class=’fa fa-pen’][2]”).click`
and see if that works for you, a similar solution worked for me.